Approach to retrieving tables from PDF files
I am attempting to make a mostly python program for scanning through research papers and retrieving tables(Any tables for now, hopefully change it to specific tables later). However, I'm realizing PDF files are the worst thing ever made, and because of inconsistencies in research paper, no library I've tried like tabular, camelot, etc. has worked consistently.
My other idea was to use Open AI apis and try to get Chatgpt to do the gruntwork, but GPT 3.5 seems inconsistent and GPT4 can't take in enough tokens to read a PDF file. Maybe I train one?
If anyone has any basic ideas on how to approach this and have a decent success rate at retrieving these tables, that would be be great!
(This is different from the other posts people gave since I wouldn't know where tables are in the PDFs. I want it to work on arbitrary PDF files which may contain tables.)
